# Not safe to lookup objc runtime data

Tags: iphone, xcode

Every now and then I start getting this error in the debugger constantly.   Sometimes the debugger will flat out hang, some times it will pause for a minute.   This is just when stepping through all objective-c code.

Any thoughts on what might cause it?    I just started using a static library, and I'm stepping through static-library code and it seems that may be aggravating it.

Comment: You cant really be helped without providing more info. Some questions: What is the error? Is this a particular part of the code or random areas? Does the app hang when you are not stepping through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be that there is a malloc going on in a parallel thread.  Check out this guys solution: http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/blog/2010/04