# app crash in ios 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

My app is working fine for iOS 5.1 simulator and less but its getting crashed for ios 6 simulator. No changes done in code for both versions. At debugging this error appears:

```
[unknown]Not safe to look up objc runtime data.
```

After googling i found this link.

[Not safe to lookup objc runtime data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293523/not-safe-to-lookup-objc-runtime-data)

but nothing helped right for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint to find where the crash is occurring. Or print the stack trace at crash time.

Comment: Check [emclstcd](http://emclstcd.tk/)

Comment: I tried with @try-@catch block, but @catch block not catching the exception